# python multiprocessing.Queue not putting through all the values

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have some lists of multiprocessing.Queues to communicate between two processes. I want to send a "None" as a last value on each one of the Queues to indicate to the second process the end of the data stream, but this does not seem to always work (I get the None in some of the Queues but not in each one of them) unless I add at least one print() after one of the put() instruction.

Clarification: It works sometimes without the print, but not always. Also, when I put the print instructions, this works so far 100% of the time.
I have also tried setting block=True for the put() method, but this does not seem to make any difference.

I found this solution wile trying to debug the problem, to find out if I'm having problems while putting the values in the Queue or while getting them, but when I put a print() on the put() side, the code always works.

**EDIT:**
A simplified but complete version that reproduces in part the problem: I have identified two potentially problematic parts, marked in the code as CODEBLOCK1 and CODEBLOCK2: If I uncomment either one of these, the code works as expected.

**minimal_example.py:**

```
import multiprocessing, processes


def MainProcess():

    multiprocessing.set_start_method("spawn")
    metricsQueue = multiprocessing.Queue() # Virtually infinite size

    # Define and start the parallel processes
    process1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=processes.Process1,
                                        args=(metricsQueue,))

    process2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=processes.Process2,
                                        args=(metricsQueue,))

    process1.start()
    process2.start()

    process1.join()
    process2.join()


# Script entry point
if __name__ == '__main__':

    MainProcess()
```

**processes.py:**

```
import random, queue

def Process1(metricsQueue):

    print("Start of process 1")

    # Cancel join for the queues, so that upon killing this process, the main process does not block on join if there
    # are still elements on the queues -> We don't mind losing data if the process is killed.
    # Start of CODEBLOCK1
    metricsQueue.cancel_join_thread()
    # End of CODEBLOCK1

    longData = random.sample(range(10205, 26512), 992)

    # Start of CODEBLOCK2
    # Put a big number of data in the queue
    for data in longData:
        try:
            metricsQueue.put(data, block=False)

        except queue.Full:
            print("Error")
    # End of CODEBLOCK2


    # Once finished, push a None through all queues to mark the end of the process
    try:
        metricsQueue.put(None, block=False)
        print("put None in metricsQueue")

    except queue.Full:
        print("Error")

    print("End of process 1")



def Process2(metricsQueue):

    print("Start of process 2")

    newMetricsPoint = 0
    recoveredMetrics = []

    while (newMetricsPoint is not None):

        # Metrics point
        try:
            newMetricsPoint = metricsQueue.get(block=False)

        except queue.Empty:
            pass

        else:
            if (newMetricsPoint is not None):
                recoveredMetrics.append(newMetricsPoint)
                print(f"got {len(recoveredMetrics)} points so far")

            else:
                print("get None from metricsQueue")

    print("End of process 2")
```

This code give as a result something like this, and the second process will never end, because stuck in the wile loop:

```
Start of process 1
Start of process 2
put None in metricsQueue 0
End of process 1
```

If I comment either CODEBLOCK1  OR  CODEBLOCK2, the code will work as expected:

```
Start of process 1
Start of process 2
put None in metricsQueue 0
End of process 1
get None from metricsQueue 0
End of process 2
```

Comment: Can you please turn this into a [mre]? The code isn't complete, so we cannot test it ourselves without making assumptions that might make the issue unreproducible, yet it is still rather extensive, making it hard to trace just what is going on. Ideally, an MRE would setup and spawn the queues/process, but have the minimal number of both – I would assume 1 or 2 queues are sufficient.

Comment: Ok, I updated my question, I (somewhat) reproduced the problem, but still don't have a clear clue of what the problem is. Also, this happens when I have 3 lists of 4 queues, but this happens too when I have a list with only one queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We don't mind losing data if the process is killed.

This assumption is not correct. The closing signal `None` is part of the data; losing it prevents the sibling process from shutting down.

If the processes rely on a shutdown signal, do not `.cancel_join_thread()` for the queues used to send this signal.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I found the problem.
Turns out I misinterpreted what `queue.cancel_join_thread()` does.
This makes process 1 finish when done sending all data, even if there is some data left in the queue to be consumed by my second process. This causes all the unconsumed data to be flushed and, therefore, lost, never arriving to my second process.